# how can i disable the Encrypt change data capture flag

Tags: platform-event, encryption, platform-encryption, change-data-capture, encrypt

how can i disable the flag in Encryption Policy - " Encrypt change data capture events and platform events "?
[image]

Comment: Please add some context to your question? Briefly explain the use case to disable the Encryption Policy.  Add some screen shots if possible.  Before posting the question, did you do any research that could have led you to a possible solution. ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the metadata object [PlatformEncryptionSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformencryptionsettings.htm), specifically the field `enableEventBusEncryption`

- Change in the UX (under `Setup | Encryption Policy`) and deploy `PlatformEncryptionSettings` to your VCS/target orgs or
- Use the Metadata API and change `PlatformEncryptionSettings` programmatically

Comment: Where can i find this metadata object? In setup?

Comment: it is exactly where you showed it in your screen shot - the check box enables the field in `PlatformEncryptionSettings`

Comment: I was not able to deploy the metadata when I include the `<enableEncryptFieldHistory>true</enableEncryptFieldHistory>` tag regardless if it is set to true or false.  When I remove that link then it deploys; it seems like that setting is read-only after it is enabled.

Comment: @JasonHartfield - interesting - what version of the metadata API did you use?

Comment: @cropredy I used version 56.   I also opened a case with support and they told me there was no way to disable it.

Comment: @JasonHartfield odd - the [doc says you can control it via Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_security_shield_enable_delivery.htm) - but I've never tried this